# Flappy Bird pygame base not defined

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

I'm currently finishing a Flappy Bird game in Python 3.8 that will be played by an AI that will learn by itself how to play the game and improve itself from its previous mistakes until a point where it will be "unbeatable". I'm really close to finish this but there's this error in my code:

`NameError: name 'base' is not defined`

This error wasn't appearing during the previous tests that I made. I looked into all the code that mentioned the base in the game but still, I couldn't find anything wrong. The game code is this:

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random

pygame.font.init()

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800


BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'bird1.png'))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'bird2.png'))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'bird3.png')))]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'pipe.png')))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'base.png')))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'bg.png')))

STAT_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)

class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel * self.tick_count + 1.5 * self.tick_count ** 2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1] 
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)


class Pipe:
    GAP = 200
    VEL = 5

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.height = 0

        self.top = 0
        self.bottom = 0
        self.PIPE_TOP = pygame.transform.flip(PIPE_IMG, False, True)
        self.PIPE_BOTTOM = PIPE_IMG

        self.passed = False
        self.set_height()

    def set_height(self):
        self.height = random.randrange(50, 450)
        self.top = self.height - self.PIPE_TOP.get_height()
        self.bottom = self.height + self.GAP

    def move(self):
        self.x -= self.VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.PIPE_TOP, (self.x, self.top))
        win.blit(self.PIPE_BOTTOM, (self.x, self.bottom))

    def collide(self, bird):
        bird_mask = bird.get_mask()
        top_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_TOP)
        bottom_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_BOTTOM)

        top_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.top - round(bird.y))
        bottom_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.bottom - round(bird.y))

        b_point = bird_mask.overlap(bottom_mask, bottom_offset)
        t_point = bird_mask.overlap(top_mask, top_offset)

        if t_point or b_point:
            return True

        return False


class Base:
    VEL = 5
    WIDTH = BASE_IMG.get_width()
    IMG = BASE_IMG

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x1 = 0
        self.x2 = self.WIDTH

    def move(self):
        self.x1 -= self.VEL
        self.x2 -= self.VEL

        if self.x1 + self.WIDTH < 0:
            self.x1 = self.x2 + self.WIDTH

        if self.x2 + self.WIDTH < 0:
            self.x2 = self.x1 + self.WIDTH

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x1, self.y))
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x2, self.y))

def draw_window(win, bird, pipes, base, score):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))

    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.draw(win)

    text = STAT_FONT.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
    win.blit(text, (WIN_WIDTH - 10 - text.get_width(), 10))

    base.draw(win)  

    for bird in birds:
        bird.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()


def main(genomes, config):
    nets = []
    ge = []
    birds = []

    for _, g in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
        birds.append(Bird(230, 350))
        g.fitness = 0
        ge.append(g) 

    pipes = [Pipe(600)]
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    score = 0

    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pipe_ind = 0
        if len(birds) > 0:
            if len(pipes) > 1 and birds[0].x > pipes[0].x + pipes[0].PIPE_TOP.get_width():
                pipe_ind = 1
        else:
            run = False
            break

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            bird.move()
            ge[x].fitness += 0.1

            output = nets[x].activate((bird.y, abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].height), abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].bottom)))

            if output[0] > 0.5:
                bird.jump()

        #bird.move()
        add_pipe = False
        rem = []
        for pipe in pipes:
            for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
                if pipe.collide(bird):
                    ge[x].fitness -= 1
                    birds.pop(x)
                    nets.pop(x)
                    ge.pop(x)

                if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < bird.x:
                    pipe.passed = True
                    add_pipe = True

            if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
                rem.append(pipe)

            pipe.move()

        if add_pipe:
            score += 1
            for g in ge:
                g.fitness += 5
            pipes.append(Pipe(600))

        for r in rem:
            pipes.remove(r)

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 730 or bird.y < 0:
                birds.pop(x)
                nets.pop(x)
                ge.pop(x)

        base.move()
        draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score)


def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
        neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
        config_path)

    p = neat.Population(config)

    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)

    winner = p.run(main, 50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'config-feedforward.txt')
    run(config_path)
```

And sorry for the such long code, you might want to press Ctrl+F to find all the locations of the base element in the code, and I thank you for the help in advance.

PS: The Base is the floor of the game.

Comment: We don't need to check all of your code, the full error message itself mentions the exact line number and line. So add it to your post. The **full traceback** provides much more useful information than you seem to realize.

Comment: There is no variable `base` in `main()`. `base` is defined in  `draw_window()`, because it is an argument, but it is not defined in `main()`. Probably `base = Base(0)` is  missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to create an instance of `Base` in `main()`. e.g:

```py
def main(genomes, config):
    # [...]

    base = Base(0)
```